# Email template of amazon

Tags: html-email

Anybody knows if amazon email template (please check this link)  http://d.pr/i/1d91T is auto generated or just separate images and links? I mean if they manually coded the template? I have a hundred of businesses and having this idea of doing somewhat like that. Or is there any other way that I could maybe create an email template that will auto populate the products when sending an email?

Answer (score 0):

Campaign monitor offers a good solution and allows to design beautiful emails. But this kind of solution is not free, you can just evaluate by yourself.